# Get Latest value from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a Kafka topic called **A**.

format of data in topic **A** is :

```
{ id : 1, name:stackoverflow, created_at:2017-09-28 22:30:00.000}
{ id : 2, name:confluent, created_at:2017-09-28 22:00:00.000}
{ id : 3, name:kafka, created_at:2017-09-28 24:42:00.000}
{ id : 4, name:apache, created_at:2017-09-28 24:41:00.000}
```

Now in consumer side i want to get only latest data of one hour window means every one hour i need to get latest value from topic based on created_at

My expected output is :

```
{ id : 1, name:stackoverflow, created_at:2017-09-28 22:30:00.000}
{ id : 3, name:kafka, created_at:2017-09-28 24:42:00.000}
```

I think this can be solve by ksql but i m not sure. Please help me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What are yours keys?

Comment: Think that key might be message 1, message 2 and so on... Above mentioned are values

Comment: Cool. Just wanted to make sure you keep the keys in mind because Kafka Streams aggregates/groups by/does everything based on keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use KSQL for this. Try the following:

```
CREATE STREAM S1 (id BIGINT, name VARCHAR, created_at VARCHAR) 
WITH (kafka_topic = 'topic_name', value_format = 'JSON');
```

```
CREATE TABLE maxRow AS 
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    max(STRINGTOTIMESTAMP(created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS')) 
AS created_at 
FROM s1 
WINDOW TUMBLING (size 1 hour) 
GROUP BY id, name;
```

The result will have the `created_at` time in Linux timestamp format. You can change it into your desired format using `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` UDF in a new query.

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can i reduce 1 hour window to 10 minutes also, it is going to any performance issue?

Comment: Sure, you can use `(size 10 minutes)`. It should not have any significant performance issues.

Comment: Thank for your response, one more question does ksql going to store data in memory or disk ?

Comment: The internal state store uses RocksDB and stores the state in memory. The results of queries will be written into kafka topics which are of course on disk!

Comment: @matthias-j-sax Is it possible to achieve this using KTable? if yes any examples ?

Comment: What if the events also include other metric properties to be included into the _latest-event_ view? We can't group by them, and using max on them will clearly give the wrong results.