# How to query the last value of a record in apache kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and so may be it is very easy. But I couldn't see any solution from the problem I am facing now. I have a Kafka topic `metric_32` and I want to find the latest value for the key `user_abc`. How this is possible in Kafka.

I tried with `KStream` but it subscribes when a new event has come to the topic. But what I want to is to query the already came last value of a key.  Any example would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Latest value from Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833832/get-latest-value-from-kafka)

Comment: If you don't know how old that message can be, you will need to read the whole topic (partition).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a state store (if you are using Kafka streams) and then add a processor to it which updates the state store every time there is a new value pushed to the topic.

```java
builder.addGlobalStore(storeBuilder, topic, Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerde), return new Processor<K,V>() {
    private KeyValueStore<K,V> store;

    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        store=(KeyValueStore<K,V>) context.getStateStore("statestorename");
    }

    public void process(K key, V value) {
        store.put(key,value);
    }

    public void close() {}
});
```

and then you can use

```java
readOnlyStore=streams.store("statestorename", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
readOnlyStore.get("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some topic you are always interested in last value for specific key, you can set `log.cleanup.policy=compact` . This way, you will always end up with just one record per key. If you produce 5 messages with the same id, only last one will remain in kafka. This way you can improve a lot disk usage if you have lot messages with same key. You can read more here: https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-architecture-log-compaction

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what log compaction does. Log compaction guarantees that *at least* the last record for a given key is stored. However, this means that potentially, you will receive older records as well. The [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) make it clear: "_Log compaction gives us a more granular retention mechanism so that we are guaranteed to retain at least the last update for each primary key_"